# $V$ need not decompose into $W$ and $W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, direct-sum

Let $B$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on a vector space $V$ and let $W \subset V$. I want to show that $V$ need not decompose as a direct sum of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$.

I know that if I can find a $B$ such that $B$ is indefinite then I will be able to find a vector which is in both $W$ and $W^{\perp}$. However, I'm struggling to find such a $B$.

Comment: For infinite dimensional spaces there are a lot of examples: consider the subspace $W$ spanned by the Schauder basis $\{e_n\}$ in $\ell^2$, and you will find that $W^{\perp}=0$, yet clearly $W\ne V$. The problem here is of course that $W$ fails to be closed, which would not happen in finite dimensional spaces, though.

Comment: Make it as small as you can. Clearly you can't find an example with $\dim V \in \{0,1\}$. So look at $\dim V = 2$, say $V = K^2$ to have it simple, where $K$ is the scalar field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. So clearly, $B$ is symmetric and non-degenerate. By $e = (1,1)^T$ is orthogonal to itself.